# Working with php files using webpack

Tags: php, webpack

I'm working on project using React on client side and PHP on server. I'm building client using webpack but my problem is that I'm not sure what's the right way to "import" .php files. I want to post to them using axios, so I need to know their place in my project structure. But if I run "webpack" my files will land in /dist folder. For example from component the path to php file would be "../../dist/php/getItem.php" but after webpacking it will change.......
How can I make some kind of special folder for php files, that would be available for me before as well as after building my components? I've found "file-loader" for webpack but I can't find any example of using it for php files.
I hope I explained my problem